# pocketsphinx recognizes partial sentences

Tags: cmusphinx

I am using pocketsphinx to recognize a series of commands, but I am getting partial sentences from time to time.

For example, my grammar is similar to this:

```
#JSGF V1.0 ISO8859-1 es;
grammar fsg.prueba;
public <ejemplo> = (<1>|<2>|<3>|<4>);
<1>=HELLO I TALK BUT I DO NOT MAKE IT LONG;
<2>=HELLO I TALK A LOT TO MAKE IT LONG;
<3>=HELLO;
<4>=HELLO I TALK A LOT;
```

If I say `HELLO I TALK BUT`, pocketsphinx recognizes that as if it was something in the grammar.

Can I make pocketsphinx recognize only whole sentences?

**EDIT:** I am calling pocketsphinx with this command: `pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k -jsgf ~/grammar.jsgf -dict /usr/share/pocketsphinmodel/lm/en_US/cmu07a.dic -samprate 16000`, and when I say "HELLO I TALK BUT", pocketsphinx shows this in the terminal:

```
INFO: fsg_search.c(1032): 208 frames, 6860 HMMs (32/fr), 8218 senones (39/fr), 2218 history entries (10/fr)

INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:37
INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:37
INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:37
INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:37
INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:37
INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:37
INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:37
INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:37
INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:38
INFO: fsg_search.c(1417): Start node <sil>.0:2:38
INFO: fsg_search.c(1456): End node I.205:207:207 (-736)
INFO: fsg_search.c(1456): End node <sil>.204:206:207 (-762)
INFO: fsg_search.c(1456): End node TO(2).189:199:207 (-1358)
INFO: fsg_search.c(1456): End node LOT.159:177:207 (-2184)
INFO: fsg_search.c(1456): End node LOT.159:177:207 (-2184)
INFO: fsg_search.c(1456): End node BUT.148:165:207 (-2522)
INFO: fsg_search.c(1680): lattice start node <s>.0 end node </s>.208
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1365): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(</s>:208:208) = -1077291
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1403): Joint P(O,S) = -1077297 P(S|O) = -6
000000003: HELLO I TALK BUT
```

Comment: It depends on pocketsphinx version, it should work as expected with pocketsphinx-0.8. Which one do you use?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I am using pocketsphinx-0.8